# jQuery - document.on hover toggle method - error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So, I've been trying to create a function in jQuery where when you hover over an element, it toggles an img, and when you exit the element, the img gets toggled again. The only issue is that this all happens after a `$(document).on` slector. I've tried using `$(document).off().on` but it's not working. Here's my code:

```js
$(document).on('mouseover', '.addressLink', function() {
  var redirectSelector = $(this).children().last();
  redirectSelector.toggle('fast');
  $(this).mouseleave(
    function() {
      redirectSelector.toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hoverDiv'>
  <a class='addressLink' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
    Click For Location <img src='download.png' class='redirect display'>
  </a>
</div>
```

This function works the first time, but then the img toggles and toggles again and again, doing it one more time for every mouseover! The event fires once, then twice, then three times, and so on. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: The issue is most likely with the nested mouseleave binding.  Every time you mouseover an element, you are going to create a new mouseleave binding, and there will be duplicates after the first time.  And since you are doing toggle, and not explicitly just doing an add or remove method, you are seeing that duplicate effect behavior.  Simple solution, use a delegate event handler for the mouseleave as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made example for you.

```js
$(document).on('mouseover mouseleave', '.addressLink', function(e) { 
  var $img = $(this).find('img');
   
  if(e.type === 'mouseover') {
    $img.stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
  }else {
    $img.stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
  }
});
```

```css
.addressLink img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hoverDiv'>
    <a class='addressLink' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Click For Location<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150X30' class='redirect display'></a></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.addressLink', function() {
  var redirectSelector = $(this).children().last();
  redirectSelector.toggle('fast');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hoverDiv'>
  <a class='addressLink' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
    Click For Location <img src='download.png' class='redirect display'>
  </a>
</div>
```

I would suggest using a single delegate for the mouseenter and leave, since all you are doing is toggling a class.  This avoids the duplicate binding issue.  There is still a little flakyness with the toggle due to the element moving and the mouse may accidentally leave the target while it is redrawing, but that's an issue with styling or such that can be addresses as a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$('.addressLink').hover(function(){
  var redirectSelector = $(this).children().last();
  redirectSelector.show('fast');
}, function(){
  var redirectSelector = $(this).children().last();
  redirectSelector.hide('fast');
}      
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='hoverDiv'>
  <a class='addressLink' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>
    Click For Location <img src='download.png' class='redirect display'>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work with dynamically created elements.